# How do I redesign this code to avoid goto?

Tags: c#, console, user-experience

Well, I have this problem because I started my journey with C# and I wrote a console calculator, but I used `goto` in it and I heard to not use it, but I have no clue what other instruction to use to make it work just how I want it to. I paste my code (it's not long) here, so maybe you can look at it and give me some tips. Thanks!

```
base:
        Console.WriteLine("First number");
        double first = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Second number");
        double second = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("What operation do you want to perform? \n1 - addition \n2 - subtraction \n3 - multiplication \n4 - division");
        string choice = Console.ReadLine();
        if (choice == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(first + second);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (choice == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(first - second);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (choice == "3")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(first * second);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        else if (choice == "4" && second == 0)
        {             
            Console.WriteLine(" Do not divide by zero");                
        }
        if (choice == "4")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(first / second);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Next one? \n1 - Yes \n2 - No");
        string chc2 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (chc2 == "1")
        {
            goto base;
        }
        if  (chc2 == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bye bye");
            Console.ReadKey();                

        }
```

Comment: Note that you can replace the lengthy if-chain by a switch statement `switch (choice) { case "1": ...; break; case "2": ...; break; case "3": ...; break; case "4" when second == 0: ...; break; case "4": ...; break; }`

Comment: Note that because you did not use _"else if (choice == "4")"_ then if someone does enter 0 as the second number - you will print the message telling them not to divide by zero - but then do exactly that.

Comment: Except for `choice == "1"`, there should be an `else if` everywhere, unless a `switch` statement is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use loops. Here's one common way:

```
while (true) {
    // do some stuff
    Console.WriteLine("Next one? \n1 - Yes \n2 - No");
    string chc2 = Console.ReadLine();
    if (chc2 == "1")
    {
        continue; // means go back to the top of the loop
    }
    if  (chc2 == "2")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bye bye");
        Console.ReadKey();                
        break; // means break out of the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: In that instance the  check for _"(chc2 == "1")"_ is not really needed as if the entered value is not 1 or 2, the loop will return to the top anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code refactored and UX improved:

```
  string userInput;
  do
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Enter first number:");
    double operandFirst = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Enter second number:");
    double operandSecond = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double? result = null;
    bool isValid = true;
    do
    {
      Console.WriteLine();
      Console.WriteLine("Select the operation you want to perform:");
      Console.WriteLine("1 - Addition");
      Console.WriteLine("2 - Subtraction");
      Console.WriteLine("3 - Multiplication");
      Console.WriteLine("4 - Division");
      userInput = Console.ReadLine();
      switch ( userInput )
      {
        case "1":
          result = operandFirst + operandSecond;
          break;
        case "2":
          result = operandFirst - operandSecond;
          break;
        case "3":
          result = operandFirst * operandSecond;
          break;
        case "4":
          if ( operandSecond == 0 )
            Console.WriteLine("Can't divide by zero.");
          else
            result = operandFirst / operandSecond;
          break;
        default:
          Console.WriteLine("Unknown selected operation.");
          isValid = false;
          break;
      }
    }
    while ( !isValid );
    if ( result.HasValue )
      Console.WriteLine("Result = " + result);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Retry?");
    Console.WriteLine("1 - Yes");
    Console.WriteLine("2 - No");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
  while ( userInput != "2" );
  Console.WriteLine("Bye bye.");
  Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit.");
  Console.ReadKey();
```